# laravel 4 raw query error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm currently trying to construct a raw query to retrieve Nearby, here is my attempt

```
$places = DB::select('select * from b_details where(3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat = ?)) * cos(radians(lng = ?) - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat))))
as distance from b_details having distance < radius = ?  order by distance LIMIT 0 , 20', array($lat, $lng, $radius));
```

I have also tried:

```
    $disctance_select = sprintf(
        "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(%s) ) " .
        " * cos( radians( lat ) ) " .
        " * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(%s) ) " .
        " + sin( radians(%s) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) " .
        ") " .
        ") " .
        "AS distance",
        $lat,
        $lng,
        $lat
    );

    return DB::table('b_details')
        ->having('distance', '<', $radius)
        ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
        ->get(array('*',$disctance_select));
```

This keeps producing errors:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

this is the query my trying to copy for use with laravel 4:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Kindly check the answer below Mr.Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check this:
It really work :)

```
$result = Listing::select(
            DB::raw("*,
                          ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( lat ) )
                            * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(?)
                            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                            sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
            ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
            ->orderBy("distance")
            ->setBindings([$lat, $lon, $lat])
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done a `select *` followed by a `where` followed by a `calculated column`.  You need to put the `distance` calculated column before the `where` clause.

Why can you not just paste the query you are trying to copy as the first parameter in the Laravel `DB:select`?  I am confused as to why you would change it.